# how to create a voice call with Twilio and react native

Tags: node.js, react-native, twilio, call, twilio-twiml

how we can add a functionality so user can make call from react native and nodeJs to some phone number using Twilio account. I have already used `client.call.create()` function but is is creating conference call I want to create real time call with 2 users. I someone can add demo code it will be also helpful.

I have already used `client.call.create()` function but is is creating conference call I want to create real time call with 2 users.

```
client.calls
.create({
  twiml:
    '<Response><Dial><Number>' +
    callTo +
    '</Number></Dial></Response>',
  to: callTo ,
  from: process?.env?.TWILIO_FROM_PHONE,
})
```

Comment: what else have you tried and found?

Comment: when I call from app to mobile using this number I receive call successfully and when I receive it transfer to third no I added in response and the two users can talk each other fine but I want direct call between app and mobile. I found different solutions but they all are automated messages not real conversations

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your NodeJS code, you are creating a call to the number defined in the `callTo` variable but when that number answers, you are returning TwiML  to dial the same number again in the `callTo` variable.

You can think of Outbound API 2-way calling as one of two scenarios:

1. Make a call to a customer. When the customer answers, call an agent and bridge the call
2. Make a call to an agent. When the agent answers, call a customer and bridge the call

So for your NodeJS code, you could have your variables called `customerCallTo` and `agentCallTo` and that can help you distinguish the calls. For your TwiML code, you will also need to define the callerId attribute, you can use the same `TWILIO_FROM_PHONE`.

Please note that what I have discussed above is making calls from the backend. If you are wanting to use React Native to make the calls from the frontend, we have a new [Twilio Voice React Native SDK](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-voice-react-native) in Beta.

Comment: no I don't want to call with an agent

I want to create out bounding call

I also tried Device.connect and when I call with that from browser it show ringing on web but I dont receive any call notification on mobile

Comment: I am using twilio client from react 
`
 device.on('ready', async a => {
          console.log('ready', a);
          a._disconnectAll();
          // device.connect(params);
          const call = await device.connect({params});
          console.log('call', call);
        });
`

Comment: hi ali, were you able to solve the above issue? i am also in your situation and could you please tell how you solved it. thanks